# Windows Service. Настройки и взаимодействие

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service

Передо мной встала задача. Нужно реализовать сервис, в котором в определенные моменты времени будут выполняться заданные действия.
Вроде бы все просто. Создается сервис из шаблона, ставится таймер, в обработку события вешается проверка по графику (если есть совпадение, то выполняется какая-то задача).

Теперь вопросы.

1. где и как хранить настройки для сервиса?
2. каким образом реализовать редактирование настроек? (предпочтительнее всего через форму)
3. где можно глубже разобрать этот вопрос? книги, блоги и т.п.

П.С. Впервые работаю с сервисами, до этого работал с web.

Answer (score 2):

1. Настройки можно хранить где угодно. Традиционно в папке `%APPDATA%\CompanyName\ProductName` или в ветке реестра `HKCU\Software\CompanyName\ProductName` (есть Roaming, Local, Common разновидности для всех трёх — место хранения зависит от того, на что влияют настройки, кому должны быть доступны, и как настройки должны переноситься между машинами).

   Формат конфига выбирает само приложение. Сейчас часто используются JSON, XML и др., эти форматы хорошо поддерживаются фреймворком, и сохранение и чтение настроек делается в пару строчек.

   Встроенными в VS средствами для работы с конфигами пользоваться не советую: они прибиты гвоздями к версии, размазываются по нескольким файлам, не поддерживают нормальной версионности, их сложно расшаривать и вообще они ужасно ограничены. Написать свой конфиг — это пара строчек кода и полный контроль в будущем.
2. Сервис — одно приложение, пользовательский интерфейс для настройки — другое (можно вместе, но не стоит так делать). Можно редактировать файл конфига, а сервис может подписаться на изменения файла.

Comment: '%APPDATA%' привязано к определенному пользователю. А сервис, как я понимаю, не будет иметь такой привязки. Или он будет заранее знать, к какому пользователю обращаться?

Comment: @Aleserche Сервис можно запускать под разными аккаунтами. Если сервис для машины, то есть `CommonApplicationData` (`C:\ProgramData`) в дополнение к пользовательским `ApplicationData` и `LocalApplicationData`.